# validate the previous tab when click on new tab in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs in my code.

I am writing my html code below:

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="userUpdateForm">
  <div class="tabbable">            
    <div class="tab-content">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="mainTabs">
        <li class="active nohover"><a href="#1A" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li class="nohover"><a href="#1B" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="1A">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="title">Field1:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <inpu type="text" name="field1" />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            <div id="titleError"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="title">Field2:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <inpu type="text" name="field2" />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            <div id="titleError"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="1B">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="title">Field3:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <inpu type="text" name="field3" />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            <div id="titleError"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="title">Field4:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <inpu type="text" name="field4" />
            <p class="help-block"></p>
            <div id="titleError"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have to validate the fields when I click on other tab,if the data is not valid it should stay in same tab.

Can any one tell me how to do that by providing sample code.

Please dont use any validation plugins,I need in javascript/jquery code to validate the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$("tabSelector").click(function() {
      if(validation condition){
         e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: But how do I know which is my current tab. As by default tab1 will be active,if i click on tab2 it should show validation message if tab1 doesn't have valid data.How it can be done,can you tell little more explanation

Comment: @user1268130 what ?? your tabs doesn't have any id's or classes ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @Baadshah answer,

You should bind this to show() event and then you have reference to active and next tab.

From the documentation:

> This event fires on tab show, but before the new tab has been shown. Use event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

And the code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
  e.target; // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget; // previous tab
});
```

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 0):

By taking the above two answer into consideration I solve my issue as the following:

```
var oldTab = e.relatedTarget.href; // previous tab url
    var oldTabValue=oldTab.split("#");
    if (oldTabValue[1] == '1A'){
        var tab1flag = validateTab1();
        if(tab1flag )
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                e.target;
            }           
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.relatedTarget;
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

    }
```